# Are commas required in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, commas

I'm wondering whether it's necessary to include commas in the following sentence:

> Unfortunately during meal service the balcony is a non-smoking area.

With commas, the sentence could be written as:

> Unfortunately, during meal service, the balcony is a non-smoking area.

While the second way of writing it seems to be better, I'm wondering whether the first way is strictly incorrect from a grammatical perspective.

Comment: Commas are used in a sentence for easy reading and understanding. Here, both ways, it works fine. Hence, it should be a matter of choice.

Comment: I prefer the second because the first version could be understood as having "during the meal service" modifying "unfortunately".